# Why won't this binded MySQL query run?

Tags: php, mysql

My code for updating user info:

```
if($update_stmt = $link_reg->prepare("UPDATE email_pass SET password=?, salt=?, customer_id=?, subscription_id=?, subscription_datetime=? WHERE email=?")){
    $update_stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $new_password, $random_salt, $new_customer_id, $new_sub_id, $new_sub_datetime, $new_email);

    if($update_stmt->errno){
        echo($update_stmt->error);
    }

    // Execute prepared query
    if($update_stmt->execute()){
        // MORE CODE HERE
    } else {
        echo("ERROR?");
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get no feedback. My data table doesn't update, but there's no `echo` message either.

Is there an error somewhere? Why won't the code execute properly?

## EDIT

Here's some sample UPDATE data and the table's columns

```
$new_password = '532a69d8124604e33e9f45a8c9xbea92c342cbd5a3f847f770816dbd97975b2769f52a25806ead6100c1ac1a9a1a4de6b1641279a26854fba7c162caffca8e9f';
$random_salt = 'b6a1062d2c07c3aa900cbe9777d4670192f77241ad0b5ceb5f7968e3107f6d719b450d2ac37165e7827f53c2005797c985deddb9bec71724948bcd833ea72e87';
$new_customer_id = '19582601';
$new_sub_id = 'crj94x';
$new_sub_datetime = '2014-02-25 19:41:56';
$new_email = 'myemail@someemailplace.com';
```

The `CREATE TABLE` syntax:

```
    CREATE TABLE `email_pass` (
 `row_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `password` char(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `salt` char(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `customer_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `subscription_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `subscription_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`row_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=239 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: so could you show us sample of data in the table? and data values you try to update?

Comment: if there's no echo at all, then you have error reporting off....so turn it on

Comment: Start by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` as the very first line.

Comment: I turned on error reporting using @RobIII code, but there's still no feedback -- just a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it works. You have a `WHERE email=?` in your code, which is populated with `$new_email`. May it be that you are trying to find the record to update by searching for the new email to be set  rather than by the current email address (or `where row_id = ...`)?

I.e. you do not get any errors and nothing is updated because you do not get a match on your `email = <new email>` where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, turns out I forgot to give the MySQL user permission to `UPDATE`. It could only `SELECT` and `INSERT`.